# Is there a Best Practice for using Streambuilders in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I've been reading up on the BloC pattern and there are some really amazing post out there that go into concise and very clear detail on how to use it:

- [Thomas Burkhart](https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/rxvms-a-practical-architecture-for-flutter-apps/)
- [Didier Boelens](https://medium.com/flutter-community/reactive-programming-streams-bloc-6f0d2bd2d248)
- [Filip Hracek](https://medium.com/flutter-io/build-reactive-mobile-apps-in-flutter-companion-article-13950959e381)
- [Brian Egan](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/12254-flutter-with-streams-and-rxdart)

The only problem I've found, is that all the examples I've seen have been fairly simple apps, and I wanted to know if you are building a complex app that has several pages/ screen, how many StreamBuilders are appropriate to have? Granted it doesn't seem like there is an alternative to rebuild a widget using the Bloc pattern beside FutureBuilder, but I assume that there is a cost to have so many streams that are active.

Comment: There is a **flutter_bloc** plugin you can use to work with bloc pattern

Comment: `fluttr_bloc` is not BLoC though. It has similar objectives, but the mean to achieve them is completely different

Comment: I wrote an article which may be helpful. https://mahdishahbazi.medium.com/flutter-streambuilder-best-practice-for-better-performance-ae41a81b266?source=user_profile---------0----------------------------